# How to get build result

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I have created a batch file which build my solution( in visual studio).How to get the build result so that I can decide weather the build is passed or failed ?

Batch File Content :
 *CALL MSBUILD %USERPATH%\EngineSln\Engine.sln*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return code of msbuild.exe would be non-zero when build fails. The way to check it in batch file is

```
msbuild.exe Path\To\MySolution.sln
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  echo Build failed!
) else (
  echo Build succeeded.
)
```